# Python smtp set up with gmail fails

Tags: python-2.7, smtp

```
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
        server.ehlo()
    except Exception as t:
        print 'setup failed'
        print t
```

Gives the error:

[Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 0):

using socks and setting a proxy fixed the issue